Tupe video clips list, the other matching durations. Itertools can find triplets that total 90 sec from duration list. Want to print clip names
I can get the triplets with iteration tools in durations list but I want to get matching clips from spots list. Tried to marry two list but dont know how to apply iteration combo on one part of the pair. Can I copy index enumeration from the 'result' and print matching clips?
from itertools import combinations

spots = ("clip1", "clip2", "clip3", "clip4", "clip5", "clip6", "clip7", "clip8", "clip9", "clip10")
durations = (30, 15, 5, 15, 30, 15, 15, 60, 25, 60)
spot_dur = list(zip(spots, durations))
#print(spot_dur)

#def find_triplets(spot_dur, target):
def find_triplets(durations, target):
   triplets = []
   #for combo in combinations(spot_dur, 3):  #error unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
   for combo in combinations(durations, 3):
      if sum(combo) == target:    
         triplets.append(combo)
   return triplets


target = 90
#result = find_triplets(spot_dur, target)
result = find_triplets(durations, target)
print(result)

for index, item in enumerate(spot_dur):
    print(f"{item}: {result[index]}")

result when I tried index enumerating 'result'
('clip1', 30): (15, 15, 60)
('clip2', 15): (15, 15, 60)
('clip3', 5): (15, 15, 60)
('clip4', 15): (15, 15, 60)
('clip5', 30): (15, 15, 60)
('clip6', 15): (15, 15, 60)
('clip7', 15): (5, 60, 25)
('clip8', 60): (5, 25, 60)
('clip9', 25): (15, 15, 60)

What I want is (for example)...
(clip1, clip4, clip6)
(clip6, clip7, clip2)
(clip7, clip6, clip9)
....


Where do those triplets in the desired result come from?

Why do you want (clip1, clip4, clip6)? The sum is 60, not the target 90.

Change find_triplets() to just sum the durations component of spot_dur.
def find_triplets(spot_dur, target):
   triplets = []
   for combo in combinations(spot_dur, 3):
      if sum(x[1] for x in combo) == target:    
         triplets.append(tuple(x[0] for x in combo))
   return triplets


The first and the winning answer. So x[1] is the second element and x[0] is the first element of the pair in a tuple? Did not know that. Tx! Now I was able to randomly pick one triplet. with i = random.randrange(len(result)), Great!

@vjekosa You know, you don't have to take the pairs apart if you don't build them in the first place, i.e., if you don't zip.

@vjekosa How did you think you used tuples if you didn't know about indexing them?

@nocomment If you don't zip them, how will you get the corresponding spots for the durations that fit the criteria?

@Barmar I prefer a corresponding combinations iterator. Though I misspoke, I do zip, but at a different level. Code
